# Best way to visualize queueing theory for a Lecture on Markov Chains

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, random-walk, expected-value, mathematica

Let the Markov Chain $X:=(X_{n})_{n \in \mathbb N_{0}}$ denote, for every $X_{n}$, the number of people waiting in a line at time $n$. Now note that $X$ is a Markov Chain living on $\mathbb Z_{+}$. Then we denote $\rho$ as the probability mass function of new customers arriving in one time interval.

This leads us to the following definition of our transition matrix $\Pi$, namely, if $x,y \in \mathbb Z_{+}$ then

$\Pi(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\rho(y) , \operatorname{  if}x=0\\
\rho(y-x+1) \operatorname{  if}x\geq1 \operatorname{ and} y\geq x-1\\
0 \operatorname{  else}
\end{cases}$

I have proven that if $\mathbb E[\rho]> 1$ then the state $0$ is transient, and conversely if $\mathbb E[\rho ]\leq 1$ then the state $0$ is recurrent.

But I want to visualize this, by showing that a graph comparing two queues with varying expectation (e.g. one where $\mathbb E[\rho]=0.95$ and another where $\mathbb E[\rho]=1.05$

In terms of computation, the trials (or the time intervals would only need to be $\pm200$ and preferably computing during my presentation, and choosing for example the Poisson distribution as the distribution to be investigated.

Those are my ideas, but I have no idea where to start in terms of software, can Mathematica help me out, particularly with regards to the varying expectation? How do I go about this?

Any advice/steps are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with any math software (such as Mathematica) or any reasonable language. I used Python. I attach a picture of the code, which you should try translating into your language / software of choice.

There are three cells. The first loads the required required mathematical module ("numpy") and a plotting module. It also defines your transition kernel.

The second cell steps through the Markov chain $N = 1000$ times. Note that the previous value $x[i]$ is used to determine $x[i+1]$, as in a Markov chain.

The final cell plots the results.

[image]

All this being said, this is not a mathematical software forum.

Comment: Would this plot interactively, i.e. can I see the plotting take place or will I just see the end result?

Comment: As written it just gives you the end result. You can make it as interactive as you like. You could have it advance a step when you click a mouse, or you can make a movie, or almost anything else you can imagine -- this is programming. But these are questions that depend on the language, and Google or other forums will be more appropriate here. For instance, in Mathematica you could 'manipulate' the parameter $N$, as in  https://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/MakeAnInteractivePlot.html